# Remove the synonym mapping [generic-programming] to [generics]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

"Generics" refers to a language features in C#, Java, and several other languages.

Generic programming typically refers to a programming paradigm used in C++ (as well as in a handful other languages, where it relies on other equivalent language features), where it relies on templates (not generics) and the ability to create specializations for specific types.

They really have nothing in common, other than that both involve syntax with lots of angle brackets. One is a programming paradigm just like functional programming or object-oriented programming, while the other is a language construct found in specific languages.

Comment: Generic programming is not limited to C++, but holds for all languages with parametric polymorphism.

Comment: Do we really need more tag fragmentation? Just add C# & Java to your ignored list if you don't like those kinds of questions.

Comment: @Xeo I'd say it's a bit more narrow than that. Not limited to C++, certainly (although that is where it is most common), but IMO it requires more than just parametric polymorphism. (in particular, in C++ it relies on the ability to specialize templates, such that, for example, pointers can treated as iterators through traits classes). Regardless, it is different from "generics"

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I.... what?

Comment: @jalf: Type classes in Haskell allow similar things to template specialization, same goes for any language that has some kind of concept-maps.

Comment: @Xeo sure, and I didn't mean to exclude those, just pointing out that the generics found in, say, C# are not powerful enough to support what I would consider generic programming

Comment: @jalf So you want to create a totally separate tag just for C++'s templates (when we already have the [tag:templates] tag) because you disagree that C# has generic programming? I really don't see the need.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII no, I want to remove a synonym between two tags which *already existed* because *one* refers to a language feature, and the other refers to a programming paradigm. Would you also create a synonym between OOP and objects? An object is specific construct in some programming languages. OOP is a broad set of techniques and idioms which involve *using* objects. Likewise, generic programming is a paradigm, while *generics* are a language construct

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII No. We are saying that *generic programming* should not redirect to *generics* which is something that is a language feature in certain languages (but not all, see: templates). *generic programming* should refer to the paradigm, not a language feature.

Comment: @jalf You also have to look at the on-topicness of questions like that. If we are talking about a programming paradigm, how do we keep answers objective, and not opinion-based? It's not like there's letters etched in stone about what 'generic programming' is, right?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII so, following this logic, OOP should be mapped to "objects" and functional-programming should be mapped to "functions"? Are you trolling?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Perhaps a simile would explain the situation better. Right now, it's roughly as if Physics.SE had a mapping from "gas" to "gasoline". Everybody would be stuck referring to all gasses as "gasoline", even though only a few people in one benighted country treat "gas" as a synonym for "gasoline" (and even there, it's not used when talking about physics).

Comment: @jalf What is the procedure to set up synonyms? Who is responsible? Maybe this person could get things back.

Comment: @Riga anyone can propose new synonyms, and AFAIK, once they've gotten a handful of votes they are automatically set up. But I don't believe there is a similar automatic process for *removing* it.

Comment: @jalf this situation is crazy, plenty of newbies decided to do wrong thing by voting and you can do nothing with it. I believe there should be some additional approving mechanism for such things.

Comment: You can't be a *complete* newbie, @Riga. You have to have some amount of reputation in the tag in order to propose or vote on tag synonyms. Of course, it doesn't mean that mistakes can't happen. I can see how someone could easily misunderstand the distinction between these two tags. Fortunately, moderators can reverse tag synonyms. Jalf has initiated the process by coming here and asking this question.

Comment: Yeah, the process is far from perfect, but it isn't *completely* stupid either. There are some failsafes in place. :) 99% of the time it works fairly well

Comment: @jalf I created a wiki page for the tag, but I don't have enough reputation to make it publicly available, could you please help with this?

Comment: @jalf It looks like I understand why this problem arose. You can look in the generics tag description and find that it actually speaks about generic programming but surprisingly names generics the same as generic programming. That is why many questions are already impacted. I believe we should do something with this. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/generics/info

Comment: @Riga Good catch. I don't have time for a detailed write-up at the moment, but I did a quick rewrite. Hopefully the next person who sees it will flesh it out. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The synonym (now removed) was created back on April 23 and it had only been invoked 3 times since then (compare to around 1200 posts tagged [generics](/questions/tagged/generics) in that time).  The tags were never merged, so not a lot of damage had been done.

---

(Note: There is no wiki for [generic-programming](/questions/tagged/generic-programming), so maybe someone who knows more about it than I do could create that?)

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I created a wiki page for the tag, but I don't have enough reputation to make it publicly available, could you please help with this?