# I get unrelated [tag:generics] tagged Q in my inbox via [tag:generic-programming] subscription

Tags: support, tags, subscription

But these tags are about different things.
Usually [generics](/questions/tagged/generics) are for .NET specific syntax/asage Q, but [generic-programming](/questions/tagged/generic-programming) is for generic algorithms and design patterns.

The problem is I don't want to receive .Net Q notifications because this is not what I have subscribed for. I treat this situation as a bug. This has started a week ago and makes SO notifications useless for me.

Comment: Please check that [tag:generic] has [4 synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/generics/synonyms)

Comment: @hjpotter92 This just makes no sense to make generics a synonym to generic-programming. For example templates are not included in the list but they relate to generic programming in the same way as generics. How can I change this?

Comment: Generics (C#, etc) and templates (C++) are two COMPLETELY different things.

Comment: @ColeJohnson in what sense generics refer to generic-programming stronger than templates?

Comment: Related: [Remove the synonym mapping \[generic-programming\] to \[generics\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191866/remove-the-synonym-mapping-generic-programming-to-generics)

Comment: @animuson thank you for the link. You have big rating so I suggest you know how things are done here. What could make this request executed?

Comment: Time. And upvotes.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks. But what is the procedure to set up the synonyms? Who is responsible? Maybe this person could get things back.